# rails4 Rspec 0 failures, but fill_in "string" does not fill_in as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run Rspec I get this response:

Finished in 1.91 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures, 2 pending

Which is great except that in the tasks_spec.rb I'm asking it to edit and fill_in an updated task and it doesn't do so. I'm new to rspec and coding in general, but it appears to me that I am getting feedback that does not correctly relay what has happened. The task that was suppose to updated was not updated.

1. Why am I getting 0 failures if this isn't updating?
2. Why isn't the task am asking to be edited being updated with the fill_in string?
3. Why after running rspec and the browser opening does clicking the edit link bring me to             an error message?
   Why does it all work manually while checking in localhost, but not in the browser after running rspec?

Everything works as expected when I check it manually through localhost:3000.

---

tasks_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Tasks" do
  before do @task = Task.create task: "go to bed" 
  end
  describe "GET /tasks" do
    it "display some tasks" do    
      visit tasks_path
      page.should have_content "go to bed"
    end

    it "creates a new task" do
      visit tasks_path
      fill_in 'Task', with: "go to work"
      click_button 'Create Task'

      current_path.should == tasks_path
      page.should have_content "go to work"
      save_and_open_page
    end
  end

  describe "PUT /tasks" do
    it "edits a task" do
      visit tasks_path
      click_link "Edit"

      current_path.should == edit_task_path(@task)

      #page.should have_content "go to bed"
      find_field('Task').value.should == "go to bed"

      fill_in 'Task', :with => "updated task edit"
      click_button 'Update Task'

      current_path.should == tasks_path

      page.should have_content "updated task edit"
    end
   end
 end
```

---

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @task = Task.new 
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def create 
   Task.create params[:task].permit(:task) 
   redirect_to :back 
  end 

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task].permit(:task))
      redirect_to tasks_path
    else
      redirect_to :back 
    end   
  end
end
```

---

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Tasks</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<ul>
  <% for task in @tasks %>
    <li><%= task.task %>
      | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

---

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @task do |f|%>
  <%= f.label :task %>
  <%= f.text_field :task %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your spec helper for `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`. If that's in there, that means all database interactions get performed from within a transaction, essentially nullifying any changes done to the database during the test. If you wish to perform this cleaning manually, I would suggest setting that to false and checking out the [database cleaner gem](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner).

Comment: I changed config.use_transactional_fixtures to false to see what would happen. I see that it adds an additional "go to bed" task without deleting the one already there, which I assume is why you're suggesting I check out "database cleaner gem." But it still won't replace the go to bed task with the new task I ask it to fill_in. After reading a little of the suggested gem language, I don't think that it would help me with that issue. I feel like I am half way there. Why won't it fill in with the new string?